# Can a gwt app be converted/packaged as windows universal app?

Tags: gwt, uwp

I have a gwt developed website that already runs 100% client-side (by which I mean no server-side javascript is used)

As one of the options for windows universal app development is javascript, is it possible to somehow turn a online gwt app into a offline uwp one?

I am aware there are solutions to package websites together with browser+installer, but if windows can run js 'natively' now (I assume via Edge) it seems a better route.

Answer (score 2):

You can use UWP Javascript project from Visual Studio. This project allows you to  add any HTML/CS/JS requires files. You can also use the Hosted model, where your files are downloaded from a URL (but then the app will require connectivity).

I've not tried the scenario, but I don't see any impediments, it should work.